# config(['app.timezone' => '']) does not work

Tags: php, laravel, config

In my service provider `boot()` I have the following:

```
    config([
        'app.name' => 'Elephant',
        'app.url' => 'http://elephant.dev',
        'app.timezone' => 'America/Toronto',
    ]);
```

`app.name` and `app.url` both work fine, but `app.timezone` does not work. My configuration is NOT cached.

I'm saying it does not work because when I `create()` a record in the database, it is still using `UTC` for the `created_at` column and not `America/Toronto`.

Why is this happening and how to I make it work?

Comment: Maybe you just need to reset the app and clear cache....try it and give a feedback.

Comment: I said in OP the config is NOT cached. And even if it was, why would the name and URL change but not the timezone??????

Comment: What do you have in config/app.php under timezone??

Comment: It is using `UTC`

Comment: So that is maybe overriding your code...where did you put it. that array config([ ])... and to be honest I haven't seen anyone make an array of config settings.

Comment: Did you read the OP?

Comment: Yes I did. Where exactly do you call that function config([ ])?

Comment: In the app service provider `boot()` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159880/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-kjdion84).

Answer (score 1):

Make an environment variable in `.env` file

```
APP_TIMEZONE='America/Toronto'
```

and then in `config/app.php` set timezone to this

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),
```

If this is not solving the problem then just post in comment and I will delete the answer.